# Android Emulator Keyboard disappears

Tags: android

When I create Android emulator with resolution 480 X 854 (to match Mot Droid ), the onscreen keyboard disappears. Why?

Answer (score 0):

That resolution does not have a skin associated with it. Is there a reason you need the on screen keyboard?
Try the below link for some skins.
http://teavuihuang.com/android/